# vue.js component not updated after vuex action on another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've a component which render a booking table; When I update my store in another component, the table isn't updated (but the store does and so the computed properties; My guess is that the problem is related to the filter not being updated but I'm not sure at all.

To do so, I've a vuex store:

```
...
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    bookings: [],
    datesel: '',
  },
  getters: {
    bookings: (state) => {
        return state.bookings
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_BOOKINGS: (state, bookings) => {
        state.bookings = bookings
    },
  },
  actions: {
    setBookings: ({commit, state}, bookings) => {
        commit('SET_BOOKINGS', bookings)
        return state.bookings
    },
  }
})
export default store;
```

The table is basically a v-for with a filter:

```
 <template v-for="booking in getBookings( heure, terrain )">
```

Where getBookings is a method:

```
getBookings(hour, court) {
              return this.$store.state.bookings.filter(booking => booking.heure == hour && booking.terrain == court);
            }
```

I've another component which will update my bookings state through a method:

```
bookCourt() {
                axios.post('http://localhost/bdcbooking/public/api/reservations/ponctuelles',
                  {
                        date: this.datesel,
                        membre_id: '1',
                        heure: this.chosenHour,
                        terrain: this.chosenCourt,
                        saison_id: '1'

                  })

              .then(response => {
                // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                console.log(response.data);

              })
              .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
              })
              axios.get('http://localhost/bdcbooking/public/api/getReservationsDate?datesel=' + this.datesel)
              .then(response => {
                // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                console.log(response.data);
                this.bookings = response.data;

              })
              .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
              })
              $(this.$refs.vuemodal).modal('hide'); 

            }
```

While this.bookings is a computed property:

```
computed: {
          bookings: {
            get () {
                return this.$store.getters.bookings
            },
            set (bookings) {
                return this.$store.dispatch('setBookings', bookings)
                console.log('on lance l action');
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Your getter is completely pointless as you can just do `this.$store.state.bookings` and get the exact same thing. You also don't need the `setBookings` action as it isn't doing anything asynchronous: just use the mutation `this.$store.commit('SET_BOOKINGS', bookings)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is not updated because getBookings is a simple method and hence the method won't be fired again based on vuex state changes.

You can make this getBookings method as an computed property that returns filtered results and will also upadte on state changes.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I pass parameters to computed properties ?

Comment: No you cannot pass parameters in computed properties. Rather you can use a variable to track changes in your store and on its update call the method.